# Using tags, JavaScript throws: Type Error: Cannot convert 'I' to object

Tags: bug, tags, javascript, firefox, opera

In Firefox I receive `I is undefined` in the Error console. In Opera I get a more elaborate message including a stacktrace:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'I' to object
Error thrown at line 1, column 5816 in <anonymous function: a.Autocompleter>(H, I):
    y+=I.length;
called via Function.prototype.call() from line 50, column 7983 in <anonymous function: each>(G, K, F) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js:
    J=G[++H]
called from line 1, column 5594 in d():
    a.each(D,function(H,I){y+=I.length;if(G<=y){z=H;return false}y+=E});
called from line 1, column 3334 in <anonymous function: a.Autocompleter>(y):
    if(d())
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 19, column 31639 in <anonymous function: handle>(K) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js:
    K.data=H.data;
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 19, column 26745 in <anonymous function: add>() in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js:
    return typeof o!=="undefined"&&!o.event.triggered?o.event.handle.apply(arguments.callee.elem,arguments):g
```

While asking a question, to receive this error, all you have to do is:

- Type anything in "Tags" when asking a question, hit Tab or Enter to select
- Type " " (space) to get the suggestion list again
- Type anything that can be selected and try to select
- BOOM! error as above in any browser

If you don't look at the error console, nothing happens: the selected tag will not be added to the list of tags.

Comment: Can't reproduce on CHrome. The current behavior is that spaces are just removed, which makes sense since they delimit tag endings. Probably got fixed in the span of 3 years

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you mean.

I'm unclear why "typing a space" is necessary, though -- simply do this:

1. go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
2. [tab] to the tags field
3. type the beginning of a tag, say "disc", and press [enter]
4. goto 3.

Comment: I thought the extra space was necessary to get the dropdown list. An automatism (ctrl-space gives suggestions in VS and other IDE's). Indeed, if you are careful, the error doesn't pop. But there shouldn't be a need for the error either ;-). Btw, if you do as you say and hit Enter without using the arrow keys first, you submit the question immediately (Op, FF).

Comment: perhaps this can be summarized that having two spaces will break the tab==select. It sounds as rather trivial to solve (but doesn't it often). *PS: should, on Meta, answers be accepted when a bug is confirmed (as is the case here) to place it on the "TODO" list, however trivial the issue is?*