# Tag suggestion/autocompletion breaks when a partial tag is preceded by an extra space

Tags: bug, tags, autocomplete, tag-autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using tags, JavaScript throws: Type Error: Cannot convert ‘I’ to object](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46522/using-tags-javascript-throws-type-error-cannot-convert-i-to-object)

There are two cases that can reproduce this. Start on the [ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page. Perform the following steps in the Tags text box.

Case 1:

1. Put a space at the start of the string
2. Enter a partial tag, say "discu"
3. Wait for the suggestion list to drop down
4. Try to click "discussion"

Case 2:

1. Put in a valid tag at the start of the string (no space)
2. Put two spaces after the first tag
3. Perform steps 2-4 from Case 1

Expected behaviour: the partial tag is autocompleted to the tag that gets clicked in the suggestion dropdown.

Actual behaviour: no suggested tag can be clicked, the suggestion list does not disappear, and the partial tag does not get autocompleted.

This can be repro'd on all sites, including the beta Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Well *that's* a nice searchable title for this error! lmfao