# Any ideas why my question was downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

This is [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77730) I'm referring to. Can you find anything wrong with it?

possibles:

- Maybe it's not clear enough?
- Maybe she thinks the bug is too minor to even mention?
- Maybe the fix is so expensive (heavy on the server and/or hard to do)?

I know I'm asking you to speculate, but I just need some feedback, especially because I din't really get comments.

Comment: Meta downvotes are generally used to express disagreement.  Unless the user leaves a comment we can't know for certain, but in your case it probably means that they feel it's not a problem worth fixing.

Answer (score 5):

Downvotes on Meta can mean one of the following:

1. Disagreement.
2. Inadequate searching by the user for duplicates.
3. Tone in question (although yours doesn't fit this).
4. Inadaquate specificity in question.
5. In the case of bugs, it may mean the downvoter doesn't think it's even an issue.

There are probably more, and this isn't meant to be an exhaustive list.

**One final note:**

> Try not to take it personally.

Comment: I'll trying holding them tears back =(

Answer (score 1):

Your question was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68008/going-back-after-voting-shows-the-page-without-my-vote-in-chrome), which showed up 5th in the suggested question list (last on the visible part of the list) when I put your chosen title into a new question, so I suspect that is the reason. I don't see anything technically wrong with the question itself. It could be that someone was having a bad day... who knows.

What could be improved? Perhaps a bit more effort should be put into searching for existing questions that discuss the same topic. No one is immune to posting duplicates (myself certainly included), but most of the time it's possible to find the original question. <sup><sub>Except [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56323/).</sub></sup>